# How to add functionality when my API response types are defined as interfaces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React application, and in order to make refactoring easier, I need to add an extension method on my Product type:

```
product.hasAbc() // boolean check that references the attributes property
product.hasDef() // boolean check
```

Currently my API returns a response which then gets bound to a typescript interface type.

Below is my Product `Interface`, and then `decoder` that decodes the API json response.  My actual axios function uses the product decoder.

```
export interface Product {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly attributes: ReadOnlyArray<string>,
  ...
}

export const productDecoder = JsonDecoder.object<Product>(
  {
    id: JsonDecoder.string,
    ...
  },
  "Product"
);

async function decodeResponse<T>(decoder: JsonDecoder.Decoder<T>, responseData: any): Promise<T> {
  return decoder.decodePromise(responseData);
}



export async function getProduct(): Promise<Product> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    customAxios.get("/api/products/123")
      .then(response =>
        decodeResponse<Product>(productDecoder, response.data).then(resolve).catch(reject)
      )
      .catch(error => reject(pathOr("Error...", errorMsgPath, error)));
  });
}
```

How can I add extension methods on the attributes so I can do:

```
const hasAbc = () => {
   this.attributes.contains("abc")
}
```

Reference: The project is using ts.data which is a decoding library: https://github.com/joanllenas/ts.data.json

Comment: If you can rephrase your question without reference to react (assuming it's not really *about* react) so that the [mre] doesn't depend on it, then you might get more engagement.

Comment: Why does it need to be an extension method? Why not add the method to the interface? Or are you trying to avoid implementing it in each class / object that satisfies the interface?

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to recommend a slightly different approach that I think gets at the functionality you are looking for.

First, as noted by others, an interface is a Typescript language feature not a JavaScript language feature. It’s used for static type checking during compile time, and that’s it; there is no object or class that gets created in the resulting JavaScript. As such, you can’t extend it. If you wanted to be able to extend it you’d need to use a class instead of an interface.

What you can do, however, is define special functions that will evaluate a given instance of your Product interface and inform Typescript whether or not it it has additional properties. These special functions are referred to as type guards (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

So, for instance, you could write a *hasAbc* type guard like so:

```
function hasAbc (p : Product): p is Product & { abc: string } {
  return _.isString((p as any).abc);
}
```

Now if you use this function in an if-block, the typescript compiler will be happy when you reference the field *abc* from a Product:

```
function work(p: Product) {
  …
  if (hasAbc(p)) (
    // no type script error!
    const abc = p.abc; 
    …
  }
  …
}
```

---

EDIT: While there doesn't appear to be any official means of having Typescript validate the contents of an array, you might be able to accomplish something to the same effect by using a special metadata interface in your decoded object that contains index mapping info.

```
interface Metadata {
  indexOfAbc?: number | undefined; // if undefined then its not in the array
};

interface Response {
  data: any[];
  meta: Metadata;
}

function hasAbc(r: Response): r is Response & { meta: { indexOfAbc: number }} {
  return (r.meta.indexOfAbc !== undefined);
}
```

Now you can safely access `abc` from the array if present and so desired:

```
if(hasAbc(r)) {
  r.data[r.meta.indexOfAbc]; // type safe
} else {
  // error: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type
  r.data[r.meta.indexOfAbc]; 
}
```

Although you should also strongly consider decoding the array into an object with an interface if it has a consistent structure rather than leaving it as an array. But I'd need to see more of the code to understand how best to model your situation.

Comment: the "abc" string has to be in the `attributes` array collection, not a property...does that make it still possible?

Comment: could I write a function that takes the response of the decoder.decodePromise and then use that response as a constructor into a class?

Comment: @Blankman it looks like there is a history of other people requesting the same kind of type guards to assert the inclusion of array entries - so you might try some of their work-arounds (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31018). Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to have an officially documented solution.

Comment: @Blankman you could certainly use your decoding logic to always use a particular implementation / class, which you could in turn apply a standard extension method to. However, then you'd probably need to go throughout your code and update your interface references to the name of the class. That or add a `.d.ts` file to extend the interface in a manner that Typescript acknowledges (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html#dts-files)

Comment: @Blankman If the array in question has a consistent structure / entries, you might consider either transforming it into an object that follows an interface, as above with `abc` or else adding a meta data interface that contains a mapping to particular indexes in the array that are of interest. (I'll edit the above post with details)

Comment: @Blankman OH! Don't know why I didn't think of this earlier, but when you deserialize the response, you can convert the attributes array into a Set. Then you can just do `product.attributes.has('abc')` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new method on `Array` object prototype. E.g:

```
Array.prototype.IsTrue = function () {
    return true;
}
```

Then use it:

```
product.attributes.IsTrue()
```

But this method will exist on every instance of Array object. E.g: `[1,'abc'].IsTrue()` is a valid usage.

You can't define the extension method for only one interface of your choice, because javascript actually don't have the notion of `Interface` or `Type`. It's just a language feature that Typescript bring up to help your developer life easier.

The recommended approach in React world would be some Utility functions, you import and use them on demand.